# Transferring SPICE models into Eagle

Tags: eaglecad, spice, eda

I am conscious that EDA questions [may be off-topic](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7031/are-eda-software-questions-off-topic), but I think this is a general use and operation question.

I wrote this in the context of using Fusion 360/Eagle in circuit design. I am trying to model specific components, in this case, trans-impedance amplifiers. I can [download the SPICE model](https://www.analog.com/media/en/simulation-models/spice-models/ad549.cir) from Analog Devices.

Running from Eagle, I encounter two problems.

1. In Eagle/Fusion360 when I attempt to combine the spice model with the [ECAD model](https://vendor.ultralibrarian.com/adi/embedded?vdrPN=AD549JHZ), not all the pins are defined - the offset null pins are missing and in this is the case ground. Why do some models not include all the pins, and leave it to the user to add the remaining pins?
2. Unfortunately, when I import this SPICE model into Fusion 360 (adding additional pins), I get an error (I simply cannot accept the model), with no explanation as to what is going wrong. What should I be checking to make sure the model is compatible/fix it?

Comment: The SPICE model/subcircuit doesn't always translate to a physical part.  I would say with more complicated parts with metal tabs, gnd pads, etc it rarely does.  Typically with opamps, to make importing into your desired simulation program easier the SPICE subcircuit will be the standard 5 pins to fit to a generic 5 pin opamp symbol.  The other pins are not modeled in this instance. You're not using the subcircuit in its intended fashion which is why you're running into trouble.  For your specific problem, maybe try the EAGLE support forums?: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/eagle-forum/bd-p/3500